# Storing only one entity of bidirectional OneToOne relationship with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Situation**:

- I'm using Spring (data) and Hibernate.
- I have two entities with a bidirectional `@OneToOne` relationship.
- Both share the same key (using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`)

**Problem**:

- I want load A and B from the database
- I want to temporarily modify B (only in memory)
- I want to do calculations on B
- I want to store A, but not B

Formulated in code:

```
a = repositoryForA.findById(a);
b = a.getB();
a.setAttribute(abc);
b.setAttribute(xyz);
repositoryForA.save(a);
```

The behavior I see however is that always both A and B are stored (Verified with tests and hibernate log)

**What I've tried**:

- Detaching B before saving A before: `entityManager.detach(b); repository.save(a)`
- No propagation `@OneToOne(cascade={})`
- Set `a.setB(null)` and detach before saving

Is this possible? Is the relationship maybe not good for this purpose?

**Entities**:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    protected Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private B b;

    // Some attributes...

}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    protected Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private A a;

    // Some attributes...
    
}
```

Comment: Make a copy of B if you are going to change it. JPA is supposed to autodetect modifications and save them so don't do that.

Comment: Thanks @K.Nicholas . I like the idea of not having to do this in the first place. The data model I'm dealing with however is not trivial so I'm trying to avoid that. And of course I want to understand why it still persists even though I detach the entity (and it's children through cascading).

Comment: I think the spring repository doesn't care if you detached it, that's a JPA thing. Spring repo has `save` while JPA has `persist` and `merge` which deal with detached states. Bottom line, you shouldn't be modifying a persistable entity at any rate. Definitely in the top 10 of "what the hell was he thinking".

Comment: I think the Spring `save` just hides `persist` and `merge`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence 
However what do you mean by "you shouldn't be modifying a persistable entity at any rate". I would like to understand that further.
Do you mean modifying without the intent to actually persist/commit that changes?

Comment: Don't try and trick the JPA/Spring Data libraries. If you want to mutate an entity without persisting it then copy it elsewhere. So, yes, that's what I mean. Copy out the data that you need, include a mapper library, anything else instead of trying to trick the data library by mucking around with detach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a similar solution proposed by @K.Nicholas . I just created a copy of entity `B` to do the temporary calculations.
I did not call `repositoryForB.save(b)`. So when saving `a` only the attributes of `a` itself were stored.